# Switching images Java Swing visbile to user in rapid succesion

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to create some sort of animation by switching between different images and waiting between them. My issue is that every time I execute this code the GUI sort of freezes then only the final image is displayed instead of mimicking an animation.

```
for(int i = 1; i<10; i++)
{
    gameplayPic.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image"+ i +."jpg"));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(200); 

        }
      catch(InterruptedException e) {
      }
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Don't call `Thread.sleep` on the Swing event thread else you will put the GUI to sleep and render it useless. Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, so I'm new to coding and I just can't seem to get the swing timer to work so any help on how exactly to do this would be very appreciated. I basically just want my main icon alternate between two images with a 0.5 second delay between them

Comment: Please again check out the tutorial that I've linked to in my comment above, and try to write your own code, simple code, that does nothing but read in several images, put them into an array or `ArrayList<ImageIcon>`, and then that starts a Swing Timer that swaps the JLabel's ImageIcon. If still stuck, ask a new question that shows your attempt and uses it to ask a much more specific question, one asks for help for fixing problems with your own code. Otherwise your question will be at risk of being closed. Please check out the [ask] and [help]

Comment: Also, have a look at my code in answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36665051/522444) that does just this: it swaps images in a JLabel using a Swing Timer.